# I built a RFCOMM server using python and tried to connect to it on the mobile phone

Tags: python, android, linux, bluetooth

I created a bluetooth RFCOMM server using python3's socket and tried to connect to it using android.

android's `BluetoothDevice.createL2capChannel` has no effect.

Android's `BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` only supports connection through UUID, but python's socket only supports connection through channel.

Is there any solution?

python version: 3.11

RFCOMM Server OS: Rasspberry Pi OS(debian 12)

Android version: 11

RFCOMM server written in python:

```py
from socket import *
from threading import Thread


class BluetoothService(Thread):

    def run(self) -> None:
        print("starting Bluetooth service...")
        s_sock = None

        try:
            s_sock = socket(family=AF_BLUETOOTH, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
            s_sock.bind(("D8:3A:DD:56:AF:08", 29))
            s_sock.listen(1)
            c_sock, addr = s_sock.accept()
            print("client address:", addr)
            data = c_sock.recv(1)
            print(data)
            c_sock.close()
        finally:
            if s_sock is not None:
                s_sock.close()
        pass
```

android side code:

```kotlin
        val bthManger = getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        val adapter = bthManger.adapter
        val device = adapter.getRemoteDevice("D8:3A:DD:56:AF:08")
        Log.i("Bluetooth", device.toString())
        // checkPermission...
        val sock = device.createL2capChannel(29)
        sock.connect()
        sock.outputStream.write(100)
```

Comment: I believe that the Python is creating a Serial Port Profile (SPP) connection. So would that make the matching on the Android side,  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket ?

Comment: Android does not provide an API for direct SPP connections. It can only find services on the target device through UUID. I don't even know which rfcomm channel it connects to by default (1-30, I used 29).

Comment: @ukBaz I just looked at some APIs of linux bluez. It seems that I need to register the UUID of my service and the rfcomm channel used to the SDP table of bluez, so that maybe android can find my service through SDP.